# Not too classical group characters

Tags: gr.group-theory

When teaching group theory, one has too speak of characters, which are morphisms $\chi:G\rightarrow k^\times$ into the multiplicative group of a field $k$ (mind that I *don't mean* representation characters). One always give the following examples:

- the trivial character $\chi\equiv1$,
- the signature over the symmetric group,
- the determinant over ${\bf GL}_n(k)$,
- $Z/nZ$, and more generally finite abelian groups.

> What other interesting examples could I give in a course at undergraduate level ? Are there examples  with $k\ne\mathbb C$ having no complex counterpart ?

Comment: Three examples come to mind: (i) For $p$ a prime, the Legendre symbol $\left(\frac{a}{p}\right)$ defines a character $\chi$ on the group of units of the integers modulo $p$, with image the subgroup $\{\pm1\}$ of ${\mathbb Q}^\times$. (ii) If $F$ is a field and $G$ is a finite group of automorphisms of $F$, then the norm map $N:F^\times\rightarrow k^\times$, where $k$ is the fixed field of $G$. (iii) If $H$ is a subgroup of finite index in a group $G$, the Transfer map $T_H:G\rightarrow H/H'$.

Comment: @JohnMurray: Why not make that an answer?

Comment: For any field $k$ and nonzero $a \in k^\times$, let $\chi \colon\mathbf Z \rightarrow k^\times$ by $\chi(n) = a^n$.

Comment: Why not tell us what actual applications you have in mind for such characters, to show the students that the concept is useful?